# wp7 toggleswitch button color

Tags: windows-phone-7, togglebutton

ToggleSwitch in WP7 has a SwitchBackground color that one can use to change the background of the toggleswitch.  I need to change the color of the slider button itself on the toggle switch.  I am talking about the rectangular block that you slide to left or right.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I think you should leave that color alone. It is automatically set to the currently selected theme accent color and if you were to customize yours, it would result in an inconsistent user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a walkthrough of changing the styling of ToggleSwitch. The translation from Swedish to English is automated, but it's not too bad.

[To make an override on ToggleSwitch style](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=sv&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.technet.com%2Fb%2Fdanwei%2Farchive%2F2010%2F12%2F23%2Fs-229-h-228-r-g-246-r-du-en-override-p-229-toggleswitch-style.aspx)

As always, be mindful of user interface guidance when modifying supplied styling.

[UI Design and Interaction Guide for Windows Phone v2.0 is now available](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/7365b3c6-9fdc-48fe-bf17-192c71f2a49f)

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the default template of the ToggleSwitch. Here are the steps to how you'd achieve this:

1. Open the project in blend
2. Right Click on the ToggleSwitch in the design view and click on Edit Template > Edit a copy
3. Now the template of your selected toggle switch would be generated
4. Search for the SwitchForeground property and set it to your desired color

You're now set